# Selenium's htmlunit webdriver resulting in Error 10061, connection is actively refused

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was using the Chrome webdrive to run a webscraper in python, and everything was groovy until I switched over to the htmlunit webdriver. I have given python.exe full access throught the firewall, but that does not seem to make a difference. Am I missing a step? The following code produces the error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:3000/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT.copy())
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: HtmlUnit is a java program and you have to configure the proxy via selenium - the HtmlUnit driver does not use the os proxy settings.

Comment: @RBRi ...so what I need to do is have the selenium standalone server running in java so I can have something to connect to when I run my python code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research and dead-ends on stackoverflow I finally found the answer... I'm dumb. You might notice while going through the HtmlUnit documentation that the java code example do not include any of this remote connection to localhost business. That's because HtmlUnit is a java program, as some have helpfully pointed out. Switching over from ChromeDriver where everything runs in python, I must have missed the part where they explain that you need to run the selenium standalone server in java if you want to have something to connect to in your python script. Selenium's documentation is a bit half baked, and so am I, I guess.

[Download Selenium Server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

> The Selenium Server is needed in order to run Remote Selenium WebDriver.

Maybe that should be included next to the documentation for how to set up HtmlUnit Driver. So it goes.